# Static images and CSS not showing (401) but bundled css and js do

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We just deployed an ASP.NET MVC 4 webapp in production and are experimenting a strange behavior : the app works but **images are not showing and part of the CSS is not loading**.

When analyzing the HTTP requests, I can see that :

- requests to images (*.png) **fail** with a **401** status code
- requests to css files **fail** with a **401** status code
- requests to bundled resources (*.js / *.css) are **successful**.

The application has worked properly in our Dev/Integration/Staging and Pre-Prod environment so I expect it to be some IIS configuration trick ....

We have already checked that :

- only anonymous authentication is enabled in IIS
- the IIS Pool user has Read access to the resources

I should add that some old HTTP modules are also configured (they take care of redirecting the user to some login page if he is not authenticated ...)

(I don't know whether this is relevant, but the app fails with HTTP status 401 when accessing its root Url (virtual directory) without the trailing slash ... i.e. `https://{the domain}/{WebApp Name}` fails but `https://{the domain}/{WebApp Name}/` works fine)

Any clue about what might be going on ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could finally figure it out ...

1. Anonymous authentication was enabled (and using default config implying that the user seen by the code is the user IUSR).
2. The files for the web app were not stored locally where IIS is installed, but on some sort of network shared drive ....
3. In that place, IUSR had no read permissions, and could therefore not read the static resources.

I had to change the default "**pass-though authentication**", specifying that local execution is not done as the "authenticated users" (IUSR in that case).

In the WebApp Basic Settings in IIS, do not use "pass-throuh" authentication, use "**Connect as**"

[image: do not use pass-through authentication]
[image]

Answer (score 22):

[image: Folder Authentication in IIS][1]]

I was able to fix it by..

1. Navigating to folder that has css files in IIS
2. Double click "Authentication" icon on "Features View"
3. Right click Anonymous Authentation as shown in the pic and select Edit
4. Select "Application pool identity" option as shown in the pic
5. Restart the website

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 401: Not authorized

What this means is that your images and css files are in a folder which requires authorization, and the web site user is not authorized to see them.

You can use:

- List item `web.config` `location` elements
- or create specific `web.config` for the css and images folders, and allow anonymous access

[Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Struggled with this as well... Solved it by using @Styles.Render("Location_and_Name_of_CSS_file") inside my shared view as opposed to the HTML "link" tag

Hope this helps somebody

Answer (score 0):

In my case none of the above was enough to fix the issue. After spending almost whole day on this I've found out that I also had to change my View to use @Url helper.

Before I had:

```
<img src="/Home/RetrieveImage" alt="" width="200" height="200">
```

It worked if I accessed via direct Url `http://localhost/{applicationname}/Home/RetrieveImage` but did not load the image on Index View as it should (error 401).

I changed it to:

```
img src="@Url.Action("RetrieveImage")" alt="" width="200" height="200"
```

and issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

To get this working with pass-through authentication:

- [Set app pool identity to NetworkService user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpXKA.png)
- [Set Connect As to "Application user" on IIS site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiYPO.png)
- Open the physical path and add read permissions for "NETWORK SERVICE and [local machine]\Users"

Although the app pool is set up to user NetworkService, local\Users also requires read access to the physical path.

Answer (score -1):

You can also try running IIS as Administrator.